# Setup SQL Agent to run SSIS Package on second server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Company is setting up new instances of SQL Server and because I have many SSIS jobs, the idea was to setup a dedicated SSIS server. It seems to be a relatively common practice and makes a lot of sense. You're removing the resources needed for SSIS off the main database server versus how we've done it historically which is to store the packages in a directory on the main database server and having SSIS compete with the same resources as the actual database. Here's where I am confused.

I was told by our DBA to place a copy of the SSIS package on a file share directory on the SSIS server. Then using the SQL Agent on the database server, create a job to run the package like normal where Package Source = "File System" and Package location being the file share directory and file name on the SSIS server. Problem is I don't see how that kind of setup accomplishes the goal of removing the execution of the package off the main database server. Won't the main database server still be executing the package thus impacting performance and all we're accomplishing is using the SSIS server as an external drive or place to store the actual .dtsx files?

Comment: Is there any special reason why you don't deploy the SSIS to the new SQL Server and set up the corresponding job on this server?

Comment: on the SSIS server with integration services install and SSIS Catalog setup, deploy your SSIS packages there.  On the other server with the agent job, create the job step and there is the option to select "SSIS Catalog", then enter your SSIS server name, browse and select the package to execute.   The SSIS is executed on the SSIS server even though the job is on another.